# How to hide debug folders in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating Android Studio to the last version, it shows me below folders! 
How can I hide these debug folders? 
[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxYhj.png)

Comment: change your view filter.  It doesn't really matter that they are visible as once you enter the folder you want, you're in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Change your project view from `Android` to `Project`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I want show Android view. why in new version show this folders?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I don't actually use the Android view and assumed it always showed all variants. Seems strange they would not have shown `debug` files before (otherwise, how would you find them?).